# JSDoc3 & DocStrap: Global menu is missing in the navigation

Tags: jsdoc3

The `Global` menu missing in the navigation while:

- The `global.html` file exists
- The `Global` entry is present in the right TOC when no template is used

Is there a special setup to use in order to ask `DocStrap Template` to add the `Global` menu to the navigation?

**Hereinafter is my setup:**

*Gruntfile.js*

```
jsdoc: {
    all: {
        src: [
            './src/main/js/**/*.js',
            './README.md',
        ],
        options: {
            destination: 'doc',
            tutorials: './src/main/js/tut',
            configure : "jsdocconf.json",
        template: 'node_modules/grunt-jsdoc/node_modules/ink-docstrap/template',
        },
    }
},
```

*jsdocconf.json*

```
{
    "tags": {
        "allowUnknownTags" : true
    },
    "plugins"   : ["plugins/markdown"],
    "templates": {
        "cleverLinks"           : true,
        "monospaceLinks"        : true,
        "dateFormat"            : "ddd MMM Do YYYY",
        "outputSourceFiles"     : false,
        "outputSourcePath"      : false,
        "systemName"            : "Name",
        "footer"                : "",
        "copyright"             : "Copyright",
        "navType"               : "vertical",
        "theme"                 : "spacelab",
        "linenums"              : true,
        "collapseSymbols"       : false,
        "inverseNav"            : false,
        "highlightTutorialCode" : true
    },
    "markdown"  : {
        "parser"   : "gfm",
        "hardwrap" : false
    }
}
```

Comment: try with the theme `cosmo` to see if this is related.

Comment: That didn't help. The `Global` is still missing in the nav (I'm comfortable with this as a `theme` should act on the look&feel not the content).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your documentation comments are specifying things that exist at the global level. @typedef is a good example of a thing that ends up being global. Here's an example:

```
/**
 * One of the following:
 * <code>'css'</code>, <code>'hbs'</code>, <code>'img'</code>, <code>'js'</code>
 * @typedef {String} SupportedAssetType
 */
```

EDIT: I'm assuming the downvote means the asker does indeed have global entries such as at least one @typedef.

Comment: The JsDoc comments in question do have `@typedef`. This is why the `Global` entry is present when no template is used as mentioned my question above.